# How to select large number of variables to pass to fable::VAR

Tags: fable-r, tidyverts

Why doesn't using the : operator when passing variables to the fable::VAR function work? I have a large number of variables and using the , separator inside `vars` works just fine, but when I switch to the : separator, it breaks. Is there an alternative way to specify a large number of variables without having to list them each individually using the , separator?

See example code:

```
library(fable)
library(tidyverse)

lung_deaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths) %>%
  as_tsibble(pivot_longer = FALSE)

lung_deaths %>%
  model(VAR(vars(mdeaths:fdeaths) ~ AR(1))) %>% 
  tidy()
```

This produces the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In mdeaths:fdeaths :
  numerical expression has 72 elements: only the first used
```

And the output makes no sense:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  .model                             term                   .response       estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>                              <chr>                  <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 VAR(vars(mdeaths:fdeaths) ~ AR(1)) lag(mdeaths:fdeaths,1) mdeaths:fdeaths     1.00  9.52e-17   1.05e16       0
2 VAR(vars(mdeaths:fdeaths) ~ AR(1)) constant
```

Compare with the correct result using `vars(mdeaths,fdeaths)`:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  .model                              term           .response estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>                               <chr>          <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 VAR(vars(mdeaths, fdeaths) ~ AR(1)) lag(mdeaths,1) mdeaths     0.872      0.362    2.41   0.0185 
2 VAR(vars(mdeaths, fdeaths) ~ AR(1)) lag(fdeaths,1) mdeaths    -0.281      0.871   -0.322  0.748  
3 VAR(vars(mdeaths, fdeaths) ~ AR(1)) constant       mdeaths   337.       126.       2.68   0.00925
4 VAR(vars(mdeaths, fdeaths) ~ AR(1)) lag(mdeaths,1) fdeaths     0.299      0.150    2.00   0.0500 
5 VAR(vars(mdeaths, fdeaths) ~ AR(1)) lag(fdeaths,1) fdeaths     0.0253     0.361    0.0700 0.944  
6 VAR(vars(mdeaths, fdeaths) ~ AR(1)) constant       fdeaths    93.5       52.2      1.79   0.0776
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you would need to construct the formula's lhs yourself, which can be done programmatically. There are plans to allow for tidyselect style selectors like `mdeaths:fdeaths`, with a working version here: https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/pull/361

Here's how you could currently select multiple variables for the model response variables, and construct the formula from them programmatically.

```r
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
library(tidyverse)

lung_deaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths) %>%
  as_tsibble(pivot_longer = FALSE)

# Select the columns you want with tidyselect syntax
cols <- tidyselect::eval_select(expr(mdeaths:fdeaths), data = lung_deaths)

# Create the formula with lhs and rhs
fm <- rlang::new_formula(
  lhs = rlang::call2("vars", !!!syms(names(cols))), 
  rhs = expr(AR(1))
)

# Use formula in model
lung_deaths %>%
  model(VAR(fm)) %>% 
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#>   .model  term           .response estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 VAR(fm) lag(mdeaths,1) mdeaths     0.872      0.362    2.41   0.0185 
#> 2 VAR(fm) lag(fdeaths,1) mdeaths    -0.281      0.871   -0.322  0.748  
#> 3 VAR(fm) constant       mdeaths   337.       126.       2.68   0.00925
#> 4 VAR(fm) lag(mdeaths,1) fdeaths     0.299      0.150    2.00   0.0500 
#> 5 VAR(fm) lag(fdeaths,1) fdeaths     0.0253     0.361    0.0700 0.944  
#> 6 VAR(fm) constant       fdeaths    93.5       52.2      1.79   0.0776
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>